# Sentence is not taking /n

Tags: css, newline, word-wrap

[image]

I am having one message box in which I am having one div with some text.
I am passing "1 am khushbu/n happy new year". It is not considering /n as command. ..It is taking it as text.
I want that if I write:

```
"hello
I
am
"
```

It should be printed in next line.
used  also.
I am using this style :

```
<div id="Stage_Scrolls_MessageBox_message_box_Text"
     class="Stage_Scrolls_MessageBox_message_box_Text_id" 
     style="position: absolute; 
            margin: 0px; 
            left: 12.61%; 
            top: 23.18%; 
            width: 165px; 
            height: 157px; 
            right: auto; 
            bottom: auto; 
            font-family: abel; 
            font-size: 21px; 
            font-weight: 400; 
            color: rgb(166, 33, 36); 
            text-decoration: none; 
            font-style: normal; 
            word-wrap: break-word; 
            text-align: center; 
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); 
            line-height: 25px; 
            letter-spacing: 0px;">
      During this Season may the joy and love of &lt;/br&gt; Christmas be yours.
</div>
```

Comment: Use `<br />` tags instead.

Comment: my text is not taking commands.../n or </br>.On console it is showing my text in next line but on view..it is not showing me in next line

Comment: You're Welcome! :) ----> http://jsfiddle.net/wufx69pb/

Comment: Or you could use CSS's `word-spacing` property if you have more text. http://jsfiddle.net/wufx69pb/1/

Comment: you can try using a pre tag http://jsfiddle.net/wufx69pb/2/

Comment: NO..this is dynamic run-time operation which I want to do...Whenever system recognize /n in text , rest of the text should go in next line

Comment: The text needs a break tag.  The text of the above DIV tag instead of using a break tag, uses this "&lt;/br&gt;" which renders the right and left angle brackets without any HTML meaning. Also, the break tag should not be written as "</br>"; write the tag as <br /> (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp).

Comment: Looks like your templating framework is encoding your html? Or you are running some sort of html entities encoding function on your text there. That's probably why your break tag does not work.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963444/angularjs-is-rendering-br-as-text-not-as-a-newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This: [The working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/wufx69pb/3/)

please replace `&lt;/br&gt;` with `<br/>`

```
 <p id="Stage_Scrolls_MessageBox_message_box_Text" class="Stage_Scrolls_MessageBox_message_box_Text_id" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 12.61%; top: 23.18%; width: 165px; height: 157px; right: auto; bottom: auto; font-family: abel; font-size: 21px; font-weight: 400; color: rgb(166, 33, 36); text-decoration: none; font-style: normal; word-wrap: break-word; text-align: center; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); line-height: 25px; letter-spacing: 0px;">During this Season may the joy and love of <br/> Christmas be yours.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br />` tag or give a specific width for the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>I am Khushbu Happy New Year</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {

width: 5em;

}
```

Change The width according to your Requirement.

You can Try like this as well,

```
 <p>I am Khushbu, <br/> Happy New Year</p>
```

Comment: my issue is : it is not taking <br /> or </n> on view

Comment: @Curious_k.shree use <p> tag instead of <div>

Comment: @Curious_k.shree please check my another answer, its working.

Comment: @Curious_k.shree its working please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wufx69pb/3/)

Comment: @Curious_k.shree after using the <p> tag change this **&lt;/br&gt;** to this **<br/>**

Comment: yes...but may be this is not an issue : my issue is i am getting "khushbu &lt;/br&gt; temp" as div content....here, <br> is not taking in consideration as command. it is taking it as string..from console , if I do "edit as html" for that div , it is showing me "&lt;/br&gt;" instead of <br> ..If I replace "&lt;/br&gt;" with <br> from element view , it is taking perfectly

Comment: @Curious_k.shree what is the purpose of using **&lt;/br&gt;** when you can directly use **<br/>** it's straight forward.

Comment: @Curious_k.shree **<br/>** --> This is the proper syntax and you can't replace it with **html-Character-Entities**.

Comment: Got solution..added above...thanks for your help..really helped me a lot .

Comment: @Curious_k.shree you are welcome. please vote my answers, if u find it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1**

Since you are using AngularJS, it looks like AngularJS is where you need to look. There is something encoding your html entities to prevent XSS.

See this answer for some solutions: [AngularJS is rendering <br> as text not as a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963444/angularjs-is-rendering-br-as-text-not-as-a-newline)

---

**Previous Answer**

I don't know what language or framework you are using, but you should check that your templating engine is not encoding your text. That's what looks to be happening here. Most templating engines will automatically encode html entities as a security precaution. There is a way to prevent the encoding by marking your output as safe.

If you are not using a templating engine. Maybe you are using PHP and are using `htmlentities` function, which will convert`<br/>` to `&lt;br/&gt;`. This is a good thing to do if you are displaying user input. It will help prevent XSS (cross-site scripting attempts).

In this case it looks like you are accepting user text, so you may want to do something like run `htmlentities` or equivilant and then do a string replace for `\n` and replace with `<br />` tag. In php you could use `nl2br`.

If you're using a templating engine, there is likely a way to do something similar as well.

Comment: yes....just found thi solution...it is taking <br/> as &lt;br/&gt;. and it is not taking it as command..it is taking it as text.....for space we are using &nbsp . for </br> what should we use? nl2br is not working

Comment: Are you using a templating engine or framework? And if so which one? That would help others provide are more specific answer.

Comment: I am using designing my view in adobe edge and using simple html pages..no other frameworks

Comment: I've never used it Adobe Edge. You may want to edit your answer to show that information since it may be important.

Comment: i think it's not that much important..issue is my <div> something &lt;br/&gt;xyz </div> .. Here , my &lt;br/&gt; should be replaced with <br> tag....Trying this

Comment: Can you describe how you are entering the text? Are you using the `text` tool?

Comment: I am having textarea :<textarea ng-model="parentconfig[configdefinition.id].text" ng-change="applyChanges(configdefinition.id,group.sceneId)" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty" maxlength=""></textarea

Comment: So the user writes their text on the page in a text area? Or is that some widget in Adobe Edge?

Comment: Thanks, it make sense now what you are doing. You are using AngularJS and outputting the user text to the div there.

Comment: hm...So is there any solution?

Comment: Yes. I don't use AngularJS, so I can't help too much. You may want to delete this question and ask the question again. Mention that you are using AngularJS and then provide some code to how you are transferring text from text area to div. You are using `ngSanitize`?

Comment: You will want to replace `\n` with `<br />` but exclude br tag from ngsanitize maybe?

Answer (score -1):

I got solution .

Solution :
It is working now....We were setting text in div..Instead of that , we should set html ..So that it can set in dom

```
textField[0].innerHTML = textconfig.text.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @Kartoch - I have found answer by my own...with help of these guys who had helped me to give hints..So done that...anyways..thanks