# Angular find tag in string and replace by real html tag

Tags: javascript, angular, replace, tags

I get a string from my back-end and when I display it, `< br/>` appears like text.

I'd like to convert them to real HTML tag or replace it by a real break line.

Here's the string retrieved from the back-end:

```
Description from backend Description from <br/> backend Description
from backend Description from backend <br/>Description <br/>from <br/>
backend Description from backend <br/> Description from backend
Description from backend Description from backend
```

Here's my function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.uns = this.sentence$.subscribe(res => {
        this.sentence = res;
        if (this.sentence && this.sentence.length > 0) {
            this.sentence = res.replace('<br/>', '\n');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you displaying it? If it's inside a text area or input then you need to replace the `<br>` with new line, if it's inside a div you don't have to do it. To replace the `<br>` you need to do:

```
this.sentence = res.split("<br>").join("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Specy :) !
I just display it in angular component (html) like this: <p>{{sentence}}</p>
I tried what you told me but it doesn't work. The text is displayed only without the < br>

Comment: I don't know, I have never used angular so I can't say. Wait for someone to answer

Comment: It works when i log it but doesn't work in the template

Comment: Thanks four your help :)

Comment: Look here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963444/angularjs-is-rendering-br-as-text-not-as-a-newline

Answer (score 0):

HTML won't print your white space characters just because you have them, it will just print the first space and then skip the rest.

You can user a `<pre></pre>` tag to fix that and then you can use something like `sentence = sentence.split("<br>").join("\n")` to fix the `<br/>` issue.

Comment: happy to help  !!

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution:

I just have to add Angular directive ([innerHtml] to format the text and interpret html tag.

Like this:

```
<p [innerHTML]="sentence$ | async"></p>
```